# In Apple's Mail.app on macOS, when accessing Exchange email, is it possible to emulate the Other category from Office 365?

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office, exchange, office-365

I use Office 365 to access my Outlook/Exchange email, and there are the automatic **Focused** and **Other** categories.

Is there a quick way to emulate the same when viewing Exchange email in Apple's Mail.app on macOS, so that I don't have to re-create the **Other** rules on the desktop?